# Create a local branch from local master

Tags: java, git, branch, git-branch, jdeveloper

I am using git versioning in jdeveloper:

I checked out form the master branch and did changes on it.
I don't want to commit my changes on master now.

I need to create a local branch from my changed local master, then commit the branch to the remote server, so that I could have my branch remotely as well.

Here is my versioning navigator:

[image]

How can I do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on `Local` and then create a new local branch under `Versioning` -> `Create branch`. Since you are on `master` right now, the new branch will be created with the contents from `master` which is what you want.

Switch to the new branch and then Right click on it to find the option to push so that you have a `<remote_name>/<remote_branch>`.

If you are not specifically fond of UI, I would suggest you to use git via command line.

In your specific case, you can create a new branch like so (while on branch master)-

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

Branches are basically pointers to your various commits. When you create a new branch it points to the current branch. When you starting making commits to your new branch the pointer for the new branch keeps moving forward. You are still on your previous branch that you were before creating the new branch when you just create it via `git branch new_branch`. You can switch to it using `git checkout new_branch`.

To create a remote branch of the same name, you can do a `git push <remote_name> new_branch`. This will create a new remote branch with the same name - `<remote_name>/new_branch`. In this case `new_branch` is said to be tracking the remote branch `new_branch`.

Comment: My new remote branch will also have the changes right?

Comment: Not sure, but either way I would suggest you to use the command line for commands.

Comment: And one more question how can I switch between master to the newly created branch?

Comment: I created a new local branch, it only added a new branch in the local folder in the navigator nothing else, so I checked out from the new branch , actually nothing happened, I mean I can see my same outgoing pending changes . . .

Comment: from the UI . . . . .

Comment: When you are on the new branch, just push to remote. I don't understand what you mean by "actually nothing happened".

Comment: I mean I didnt see any dialog nor progress waiting bar

Comment: That will not happen, don't worry about it.

Comment: OK, now when I select my new branch, the push menu button is disabled in Versioning -> Git -> Push